# Android Touch Regarding

Tags: android, touch

I have a sequence of button widgets that are residing one below another. I want to build a piano and I am using touch listener. I want to play a sound when the button is pressed and swipe across. It worked fine for individual touch of button. But I want to play sound while user swipe across button like piano. Need to catch action play a sound. I can't get action while swipe across buttons.

Comment: Remember to accept answer if answer is correct to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a gesture listener, and then implement it:
Look that the following [link](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/gestures.html)

edit:
Sorry bad link, here is a [tutorial from lars vogel](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGestures/article.html), they are usually really good:

Comment: I saw the link you posted, Thanks, I am wondering Is it possible to deduct hover between button using touch listener

Comment: I assume it is, if you know where your buttons are located :)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            findViewById(R.id.myimage1).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
            findViewById(R.id.myimage2).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());


        }



private final class MyTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                    DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(
                            view);
                    view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
                    view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```